# How can i make my text be within a border & have the lines not be behind it?

Tags: html, css, forms, border

I made a simple login screen, I just would like to know how i can get it to where login is in in the border but where i also dont see the border lines behind it. I've been trying to mess around with it and cant seem to figure it out. I also tried changing the background to see if it would do anything and nothing changed

```css
.login-container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
 }

.login-container h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', serif;
    margin-top: -1.875rem;
    color: #ffff;
    font-size: 2.2rem;

}
.sign-in-btn,
.create-account-btn{
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 200px;

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #1db954;
    transition: ease-out 0.3s;
    background: none;
    border: #1db954 solid 1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sign-in-btn:hover,.create-account-btn:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #1db954;
}
.sign-in-btn:before,.create-account-btn:before{
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    content: "";
    background-color: #1db954;
}
.sign-in-btn:hover:before,.create-account-btn:hover:before {
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="form-container">
  <h1>Sign in</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="login-btn">Log in</button>
    <p class="text">Dont have an account? <a href="CreateAcc.html">Create an Account</a>
      <a href="CreateAcc.html">Forgot Password?</a></p>
  </form>

</div>

</body>
```

Ive read something about fieldset and legend, but cant seem to work it in my code

Comment: are you sure you're giving the correct html syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the example using background to hide the border line behind the element and text within border by connecting back all your CSS classes to respective html element.

```css
.login-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
   
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.login-container h1 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: -20px;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', serif;
  color: #ffff;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

.sign-in-btn,
.create-account-btn {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;

  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #1db954;
  transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  background: none;
  border: #1db954 solid 1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sign-in-btn:hover,
.create-account-btn:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #1db954;
}
.sign-in-btn:before,
.create-account-btn:before{
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #1db954;
}
.sign-in-btn:hover:before,
.create-account-btn:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-container">
  <h1>Sign in</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="sign-in-btn">Log in</button>
    <p class="create-account-btn">Dont have an account? <a href="CreateAcc.html">Create an Account</a>
      <a href="CreateAcc.html">Forgot Password?</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```